# in option menu can't show android option.(Show red mark)

Tags: android, android-menu

[image]

in option menu can't show android option.(Show red mark)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

go to Tools --> Android --> SDK Manager --> plugins uncheck all plugins and apply after restart

after restart

check all plugins and apply and restart.